Proving $Cov(e_{ij}- \bar{e}_{i0},e_{ij}-\bar{e}_{i0} -\bar{e}_{0j} +\bar{e}_{00})=0$
I am trying, please rectify my mistakes in the following process and help me proceed further
Given: $$e_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)\\\bar{e}_{i0}= \frac{1}{q} \sum_{j=1}^{q} e_{ij}, \\ \bar{e}_{0j}= \frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=1}^{p} e_{ij}, \\ \bar{e}_{00}= \frac{1}{pq} \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^q e_{ij}$$
My attempt:
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(e_{ij}-\bar{e}_{i0},e_{ij}-\bar{e}_{i0}-\bar{e}_{0j}+\bar{e}_{00})\\
&=\text{Cov}(e_{ij},e_{ij})-\text{Cov}(e_{ij},\bar{e}_{i0})-\text{Cov}(e_{ij},\bar{e}_{0j})+\text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{00},\bar{e}_{00})-\text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0},e_{ij})+\text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0},\bar{e}_{i0})+\text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0},\bar{e}_{0j})-\text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0},\bar{e}_{00})\\
&=\text{Var}(e_{ij})-\text{Cov}(e_{ij},\frac{1}{q} \sum_j e_{ij})-\text{Cov}(e_{ij},\frac{1}{p} \sum_i e_{ij})+\text{Cov}(e_{ij},\frac{1}{pq}\sum_i \sum_je_{ij})-\text{Cov}(\frac{1}{q}\sum_j e_{ij},e_{ij})+Var(\bar{e}_{i0})+\text{Cov}(\frac{1}{q}\sum_j e_{ij},\frac{1}{p}\sum_i e_{ij})-\text{Cov}(\frac{1}{q}\sum_j e_{ij},\frac{1}{pq}\sum_j \sum_i e_{ij}) 
\end{align}
Now, using the given info, I unable to obtain 0.
Please see if there is any problem with the expression.

I think the index for $\bar{e}{0j}$ should be $i$ and not $j$ in the sum right? Also, are the $e{ij}$'s all independent?

Ok, I am assuming that the $e_{ij}$'s are all independent. We get
\begin{align}
&\text{Cov}(e_{ij} - \bar{e}_{i0}, e_{ij} - \bar{e}_{i0} - \bar{e}_{0j} + \bar{e}_{00}) \\
&= \text{Var}(e_{ij}) + \text{Var}(\bar{e}_{i0}) - 2\text{Cov}(e_{ij}, \bar{e}_{i0}) -  \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, \bar{e}_{0j})\\
&\quad - \text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0}, \bar{e}_{00}) + \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, \bar{e}_{00}) + \text{Cov}(\bar{e}_{i0}, \bar{e}_{0j}) \\
&= \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{q^2}\sum_{j=1}^q \sum_{j=1}^q \text{Var}(e_{ij}) - \frac{2}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ij})  - \frac{1}{q}\sum_{j=1}^q \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ij}) \\
&\quad - \frac{1}{p^2 q} \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^q \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ij}) + \frac{1}{pq} \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^q \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ij}) + \frac{1}{pq} \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^q \text{Cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ij}) \\
&= \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 - 2\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 - \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 = 0 \quad \square.
\end{align}

Yes e_ij are Independent .And sorry for not mentioning that and yes there was a typo-error.
Thanks Sir/Madam for the Answer.

btw ,can you elaborate how the expression obtained from $Var(\bar{e}_{i0})$?

@Error_Akash sure, $\text{Var}(\bar{e}{i0}) = \text{Var}(\frac{1}{q} \sum{j} e_{ij}) = \frac{1}{q^2}  \text{Cov}(\sum_{j=1}^q e_{ij}, \sum_{j=1}^q e_{ij})$. Then, you can move the covariance operation past the sums as in the other cases, leaving you with $\frac{1}{q^2} q^2 \sigma^2$.

got it thankyou

Since the answer is zero, there has to be an elegant solution without number-crunching.
Let $\delta_i$ be the (column) vector of all $0$s apart from a $1$ in the $i$th index.
Let $\mathbf{1}$ be the (column) vector of all $1$s.
Let $E=(e_{ij})_{ij}$ be the matrix of random variables.
Then we can write
$$\bar{e}_{ij} =         \delta_i^T E \delta_j$$
$$\bar{e}_{i0} = \tfrac1p \delta_i^T E \mathbf{1}$$
$$\bar{e}_{0j} = \tfrac1q \mathbf{1}^T E \delta_j$$
$$\bar{e}_{i0} = \tfrac1{pq}\mathbf{1}^T E \mathbf{1}$$
The lengths of the vectors should be clear from context (i.e $p$ when on the left of $E$, and $q$ when on the right of $E$).
Therefore, upon factorising, the answer is
$$
Cov(e_{ij}- \bar{e}_{i0},e_{ij}-\bar{e}_{i0} -\bar{e}_{0j} +\bar{e}_{00})$$
$$
=Cov\left(
\delta_i^T 
E 
\left(\delta_j-\tfrac1q \mathbf{1}\right),
\left(\delta_i - \tfrac1p \mathbf{1}\right)^T 
E 
\left(\delta_j-\tfrac1q \mathbf{1}\right)
\right)$$
Since we can take out the common factor $\left(\delta_j-\tfrac1q \mathbf{1}\right)$, we are left with proving that a random equi-distributed normal vector $Y := (\delta_i^T E)^T$ is independent from $Y-\bar{Y}$, which is true when we consider fitting $Y$ against $\mathbf{1}$. The result follows from linear regression theory: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515874/why-are-the-residuals-in-mathbbrn-p

Thankyou sir ,For the Answer as well as editing the question and making it more polished.
